# Easy way to convert a timestamp to a human readable date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following timestamp:  `2016-03-29T14:14:43.000Z`. Is there any easy way to use JavaScript to make it look something like the following: `Mar 29, 2016 2:14p`? I tried using `Date.parse()` but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: use the date Filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: you could use http://momentjs.com/ it has good filters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

{{yourValue| date:"MMM d, yyyy h:ma"}}

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up needing.

Comment: is there a way to add the timezone? You can just send me to the documentation if you would like. Can't seem to find it. I tried Z but that gives me something like -0400, is there a letter representation that can be achieved such as EST, GMT etc.?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ts = "2016-03-29T14:14:43.000Z";
var date = new Date(ts);
console.log(date);  // Displays Tue Mar 29 2016 16:14:43 GMT+0200 (Romance Summer Time)
```

Is that what you need ?

```
var ds = date.toUTCString();
console.log(ds.substr(0,24)); // Displays Tue Mar 29 2016 16:14:43
```

Comment: Without the GMT+0200

Comment: Modified the response and I think its what you want

Comment: Okay that is pretty close. I guess I should have mentioned that I need it to be in a specific time zone.

Comment: and for angular view,  Cirtrus was pretty close ... it's actually {{ yourvalue | date:"MMM d MMMM yyyy h:ma"}}

Comment: yeah i just tried that and it works out the best for what I need. I appreciate your help though